# how to make a child process "independant" from the main process in c++ on windows

Tags: c++, windows, process

i have this function to create a new process

```
void replicate()
{
STARTUPINFO si;
memset(&si, 0, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
CreateProcess(NULL, ::GetCommandLine(), NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
}
```

i would like to new if it's possible to make my new process like independant of the main process
for example, if i kill the main process, is it possible to make my child processes keep running ?

i will really appreciate your help

Comment: That's what happens out the box - the two processes are in fact independent. You don't need to do anything special.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik then why if i taskkill my main process it kills all the other ones

Comment: Define "taskkill" and "it".

Comment: @IgorTandetnik ok nevermind maybe something wrong in my code tested it again and  they are actually independant